# VS Code will not run program in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am on mac and anytime I try to run my code in the terminal through vs code the only thing that
pops up are these path finds does anyone know how to fix the issue?

[image: picture of problem]

Comment: Looks like you need to escape the `"`. FWIW, that is a very bad file name

Answer (score 0):

Your file somehow got named `print("Hi!").py` and the double quote is not escaped properly..

You should close vscode, rename your file to not use special characters, then try again

Comment: it does it with any of my code files even ones named just test

Comment: According to the image, it's because you ran the file with quotes **first**, and the `dquote>` prompt is waiting for a closing double quote to be evaluated ... Issue has nothing to do with Vscode or Python, since it's the terminal process returning that prompt. You can click the trash can icon in the right side of the screen, or you can restart vscode to get a new terminal and run different files